# How to sort in appscript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

im trying to sort column "a" then sort column "b".

I have a column called "Categories", im ordering it alphabetically. Then I want to order "Subcategories" alphabetically too, respecting the first column order.

```
function autoSort() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Table");
  const orderArray = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  orderArray.sort(sortFunction)
  sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()).setValues(orderArray)
}
```

This is the function i use to sort the first column. How can I do to sort the second column?

```
var sortFunction= function(a,b){
  if (a[4]>b[4]){return 1}
  else if (b[4]>a[4]){return -1}
  return 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you could always use the [Range.sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj) method.

```
function autoSort() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Table");
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn());
  range,sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 2, ascending: true}])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sort can be written to sort the second column(say Col6) instead of returning 0:

```
var sortFunction= function(a,b){
  if (a[4]>b[4]){return 1}
  else if (b[4]>a[4]){return -1}
  // they're equal:
  if (a[5]>b[5]){return 1}
  else if (b[5]>a[5]){return -1}
  return 0
}
```